# Jasmine testing async angular controller function

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

Firstly this is my first attempt to run tests in my applications. 
The below bit of code is meant to test the result of a controller function ($scope.getActiveClients(), this function makes a $http get  request) therefor the returned object: $scope.activeClients is undefined whilst my test run.
So far I have tried runs() and waitsFor() and also the done() function as stated in jasmine's 2.0 docs to no avail and getting this error msg:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
 describe 'myController', ->
   beforeEach module('myApp')
   $controller = undefined
   beforeEach inject((_$controller_) -> 
     $controller = _$controller_
     return
  )
  describe '$scope.activeClients', ->
    it 'gets all active clients', ->
      $scope = {}
      controller = $controller('myController', $scope: $scope)
      $scope.getActiveClients()
      expect($scope.activeClients).toEqual xxx
      return
    return
  return
```

any pointers will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the $http calls by $httpBackend then you can get hold of your http calls and test async calls.
I don't know coffescript but can show you in js.

```
describe('myController', function(){
 var $scope, controllerService, httpMock;
 beforeEach(module('myApp'));
 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controllerService = $controller;
    httpMock = $httpBackend;
 }));

 it("gets all active clients", function () {
   //mock http calls
   httpMock.expectGET("/getActiveClients").respond({data: 'clientTestData'});
   ctrl = controllerService('myController', {$scope: $scope});
   $scope.getActiveClients();
   httpMock.flush();
   expect($scope.activeClients).toEqual xxx
 });
});
```

Comment: although your answer is not 100% accurate it pointed me out in the right direction, thanks.